# In iOS or macOS Contacts App, I would like to duplicate a contact. What is the easyest way to do this?

Tags: macos, ios, contacts, contacts.app

I am planning to keep some of the info in the original contact and all of it in the copy, where I would later add more. What is the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: it's a text file, open it in textedit and copy the data you need out that way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up:

1. sharing the contact with myself
2. renaming the original
3. adding the shared one

Answer (score 3):

VCF files are just text files, so you can edit them in every text editor.

- Right-click on VCF file
- Select "Open with" and then "Textedit.app"
- Change whatever field you want to change (`N` and `FN` are typical fields to change if you want to change the name)
- Use "Save as" to save with a new file name

PS: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard#Properties for details about the different fields. Not all of them may be supported by Contacts though.